# python call external program non-blocking way

Tags: python, background-process

is there a way to call an external program inside python and don't wait for its execution to finish?

I tried this, but no luck:

```
os.system("external_program &")
```

Normally, if I call `external_program &` inside a bash shell it executes as a background process.
How can I do it inside python? For, my special case, creating another thread does not work. After main python scrip is done, the external program should continue its execution.

Comment: Can you run it in parallel? There are no dependencies?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, use the [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).  For example:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['external_program', 'arg1', 'arg2'])
# Process is now running in the background, do other stuff...
...
# Check if process has completed
if p.poll() is not None:
    ...
...
# Wait for process to complete
p.wait()
```

Comment: I tried this. It is still blocking. And, if it works, what happens if I don't wait at the end? Is it going to be killed?

Comment: I realized that it actually works but the main script waits at the end. I need a complete independence from the main script. Is it possible?

Comment: @GokhanKa: If you don't want the main script to wait, then don't call `wait()`, it's that simple.  If you exit while the subprocess is still running, it will continue to run in the background.

Comment: I'm not calling wait(). It does not even execute sys.exit(0) after Popen call. If I call p.terminate(), it immediately terminates the subprocess and exits. How strange is this?

Comment: Coming from a duplicate, I want to emphasize: replace `os.system("thing &")` with `p = subprocess.Popen(['thing'])` without the `&` (and without the shell) and do whatever else you want to do.  `p` will exist and be running in the background because you created a subprocess, just like the shell does with `&` and you can eventually reap it with `p.wait()`.  Things will be a little more complex and subtle if `thing` blocks because it is writing to a pipe or something, but there are other questions which explain this in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about `os.system()`. It is deprecated in favour of the [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

It provides a way to execute subprograms for almost every thinkable use case.