# How do i run a python script from another python script without the secondary script interrupting the first?

Tags: python, background, call

So I have the main python script and I want to call another python script from my main file, however, whenever I do this the script I call kinda overtakes the original. is there any way to call a python script in the background to have it not interrupt the main script in the console?

Comment: Sure, learn about the `subprocess` module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non blocking subprocess.call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071866/non-blocking-subprocess-call)

Comment: also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986658/python-call-external-program-non-blocking-way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi I make this script for you using threading and subprocess to run other python script in the background (without the secondary script interrupting the first)

```
import threading
from subprocess import call
def thread_second():
    call(["python", "secondscript.py"])
processThread = threading.Thread(target=thread_second)  # <- note extra ','
processThread.start()

print 'the file is run in the background'
```

Comment: this is great but is there any way to stop the secondary script from outputting to the console?

Comment: @invisabuble that's a whole separate question which you should either lookup or ask. LMGTFY: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125702/how-to-suppress-console-output-in-python#25061573 , https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call shows you that there is a kwarg for call that routes your stdout and stderr

Comment: hello , you can use that it's helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python