# Run python file from an other python file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two python files in the same directory.

**File 1:** ***main.py***

```py
import time
import threading
from subprocess import call

def thread_second():
    call(["python", "python_test.py"])
processThread = threading.Thread(target=thread_second)  # <- note extra ','
processThread.start()

time.sleep(2)

print ('the file is running in the background')

print('exit main')
```

**File 2:** ***secondary.py***

```py
import time
import os

try:
    file = open("runnnig.tmp","x")
    file.close()
except Exception as FileExistsError:
     print('file already exists')

print('Secondary file is running')

# do some staff 
time.sleep(10)
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to run the *secondary.py* from *main.py*. Only one problem I want the *secondary.py* to run completely independent of the *main.py* so that after opening the *secondary.py* the *main.py* exits. With this solution here, that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45403295/10674486) the *secondary.py* starts running normally but the *main.py* hangs until the *secondary.py* exits. How can I accomplish that?

---

PS. For anyone wondering what I am trying to do

I have a node.js server running on a Raspberry pi. When a request is given to the server the *main.py* is called from the server. The *secondary.py* is a script that tells raspberry to start logging values from a sensor. The *secondary.py* will run an infinite loop until another script interrupts it. That's why I don't want the *main.py* to hang until the *secondary.py* exits

Comment: You can use `nohup <cmd> &` to detach the subprocess and run it in the background.  No need for a thread in `main.py`.

Comment: @0x5453 How can I do that from the main.py? All I can find regarding ```nohup``` is how to run a script from the terminal. What I want is to "call" the script from the main.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need threading for that, and using `Popen` instead of `call` means that your `main.py` doesn't wait on the new process to end.

```
import time
from subprocess import Popen

Popen(["python", "python_test.py"])

time.sleep(2)

print ('the file is running in the background')

print('exit main')
```

Comment: Works great only one question. Is there any way to see the output of the secondary.py in the console?

Comment: You should be able to do that with the `stdout` parameter to `Popen`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments For a long-running process it might be a good idea to send it to a file so you can check it with a command like `tail -f`